# What is the use of function destroyAllWindows() if the window automatically gets destroyed using waitKey() function?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

```
#!/usr/bin/python3    
import cv2     
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

checking if camera is working!!

```
cam.isOpened():
    print("Working")

while(cam.isOpened()):
    status,frame=cam.read()
    cv2.imshow('camera1',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('q') :
            break
```

**Removing windows by calling below function**
 If i dont write this function then  also it will run properly!!

```
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
   cam.release()
```

Comment: You are exiting the script and thus the windows are closed. If you have multiple windows open and you do not need those to be open, you can use `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` to close those all. Then you can open new cv2 windows, if needed = in a sense in above `cv2.destroyAllWindows() ` is just good coding practice.

Comment: waitKey does not destroy the window... at least not in most of the cases. When the program exits, most of the time the window is destroyed, but in python if you are running it from terminal rather than a script it may linger until you close it or exit python.

Comment: @Mika72 @api55okay!!,i got your point,Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Closes all the open GUI windows.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).